# TFS ISubscriber plugin, how do I access the files checked in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, tfs

I am writing a plugin for TFS that performs automatic branching and merging based on an xml file stored in source.  I am able to perform this on the server except I am unable to get the latest of the xml file if it was changed.

```
public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
{
  TeamFoundationVersionControlService versionControl = requestContext.GetService<TeamFoundationVersionControlService>();

  string localTempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();          
  versionControl.DownloadFile(requestContext, serverItemPath, 0, VersionSpec.Parse("C" + versionControl.GetLatestChangeset(requestContext).ToString(), null).First(), localTempFile);

  return EventNotificationStatus.ActionApproved
}
```

The issue is that because I want to intercept the checkin before it becomes a changeset, the download file function gets me the version of the latest checkin, not the version that was promoted.  Does anyone know how to get the version being checked in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the artifacts field of the [CheckinEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.common.checkinevent.aspx) class.

```
CheckinEvent ev = notificationEventArgs as CheckinEvent;
```

Comment: I cannot seem to reference it.  I have a reference to Microsoft.TeamFoundation,VersionControl.Common and the object cannot be found.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.common.checkinevent.aspx

Comment: Found it, but the CheckinEvent is null after conversion.  I am subscribing to the types of CheckinNotification.  Should I be subscribing to the CheckinEvent type as well?

Comment: var checkinNotification = notificationEventArgs as CheckinNotification; 
TeamFoundationLocationService service = requestContext.GetService<...>(); 
Uri selfReferenceUri = service.GetSelfReferenceUri(..); 
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(selfReferenceUri); 
var versionControl = (VersionControlServer)tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)); 
var changeSet = versionControl.GetChangeset(checkinNotification.Changeset);

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different route: use a CI build that monitors just that file.
It is way more robust and manageable than a server plug-in.